# By what process do AdSense page level policy actions lead to site wide penalties?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

Alright, I run a couple websites which don't really agree with *Googles Policy* to the fullest how ever this is the first time I've seen anything like this happen.

[image]

And I have a couple questions for someone who may know more about this, (I've not been able to find anything online thus far about this type of action).

Does this mean my account is in any danger? It appears that they're just taking a route by removing their advertisements from troubled pages which infringe their policy. Are they not going to be disabling accounts anymore? How can I go about viewing this process in more detail? Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is a noob question I'm just beyond confused.

---

**EDIT:** I found [this article](https://venturebeat.com/2017/05/15/google-will-now-remove-ads-from-web-pages-that-violate-adsense-policies-without-punishing-entire-website/), which says the following.

“As we roll out page-level policy action as the new default for content violations, we’ll be able to stop showing ads on select pages, while leaving ads up on the rest of a site’s good content,” explained Scott Spencer, director for sustainable ads at Google, in a blog post.

“We’ll still use site-level actions but only as needed. And when it’s necessary, such as in the case of egregious or persistent violations, we’ll still terminate publishers.”

---

**However** my question still remains, what will google consider persistent? Is this a way for them to work with publishers who often violate their *Policy*?

Comment: Adsense is a service, not a right, if you keep violating the terms of use, they will eventually terminate your account.